# domain name configuration + redhat 7

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, domain, hostname, domain-name

we configured the hostname with qualified domain name

in the file:

```
 more /etc/hostname
 machine04.whitehouse.com
```

so

```
hostname
```

will give

```
machine04.whitehouse.com
```

in the redhat 7 machine we see that domain also configured as the following:

```
DOMAIN="whitehouse.com"
```

in the ifcfg file under /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts

example

```
tail -1   /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Nw

DOMAIN="whitehouse.com"
```

so why we need to add the  **DOMAIN="whitehouse.com"** in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Nw

if its already configured in **/etc/hostname**  ?

second

in which case we need to add the domain name in the **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg** file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you don't "NEED" to do this, however it could be beneficial to setting up services for the machine.

(I don't use CentOS 7 that much but) I would expect that the DOMAIN in ifcfg-Nw is used to manipulate your /etc/resolv.conf file, to add your domain - such that it will allow for searching unqualified domains by appending ".whitehouse.com" to it - so when you go to site "xxx", it will try resolve xxx.whitehouse.com.  Of-course, its possible for your computer to be have a domain name which does not imply "whitehouse.com".